# Multiple i18n submit helpers for same controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

I have some i18n helpers set up as follows:

```
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      post:
        create: "Save and Continue"
        update: "Update"
```

Now in `_form.html.erb`

```
<%= f.submit %>
```

This works great.

Now I add a `:status` attribute to my `Post` model and want to give a different message for the `:update` action based on the `@post.status` value.  Something like:

```
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      post:
        create: "Save and Continue"
        update: "Update"
          publish: "Save Draft"
```

Is this easily doable under i18n or should I just write a helper instead?

Comment: Those are not  i18n helpers - its just a yml file with translation keys.

Comment: I think he knows that(I could be wrong).  That is why he asked if he should write helpers instead.

Comment: Yeah, Sorry about the poor terminology.  Like you've said, it's good enough for 99% of the time.  I've decided to go about it a different way instead of trying to cram a square peg into a round hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
en:
  foo: "bar"
```

These are translation keys - not helpers. Helpers in Rails are modules that contain helper methods.

> Is this easily doable under i18n or should I just write a helper instead?

Yes and no.

The rails form helpers just translate the button according to the action. Which is good enough for what its used for 99% of the time.

You can use the Rails i18n module to define the translations. And create a helper method to cover your case:

```
module PostHelper
  def post_submit_button(form_builder)
    post = form_builder.object
    if object.persisted?
      concat( form_builder.submit( 
        I18n.t("helpers.submit.post.update.#{post.status}")
      )
    else
      concat( form_builder.submit )
    end    
  end
end
```

Comment: I suspected that my use case was outside of what is really doable by the default behavior.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely doable under I18n.  You would basically do something like

```
message = I18n.t("helpers.submit.post.update.#{post.status}")
```

Assuming post is an instance of your post model.